# TinyMCE or other WYSIWYG Editors for Mobile Devices?

Tags: mobile, tinymce, wysiwyg

Is it possible to use a WYSIWYG text editor (especially TinyMCE) for a mobile device or is that not supported yet? Will it ever be supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This weblink [Compatibility table for support of contenteditable attribute in desktop and mobile browsers.](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable) will give you a clue about this issue.

I was looking for the same thing today, so I thought to share this link with you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use it on a mobile device, but the javascript functionality in those browsers is limited, so not everything is possible (own plugins and several interactions with own CMS i.e.).

Keep in mind too that heavy js-usage on a page will slow down all its functionality on mobile devices cause the system is not as powerfull as a personal computer. I had the problem that the js overhead of a CMS delayed js-functionality in the browser so that clicking checkboxes and selecting input fields was almost not usable.

It might be necessary to redisign the whole CMS around such an editor to run fast enough to make it work.

Comment: tinymce works. you may verify this on using the tinymce test page at: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: I tried that on my Android Gingerbread phone. Everything display, but I could not focus to edit it...

Comment: hmm, i do not knwo what diffrences exist between a phone browser and an idap browser (safari)